# Access the second span in loop using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I access the second `span` element in a found `div`?

My code looks like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#url website
url = 'https://www.gumtree.pl/a-samochody-osobowe/krakow/honda-civic-1-5-sport-mt-2019/1006295441720911232816609'

#opening up connection, grabbing page
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

#scraping div
product = page_soup.find('div', {'class': 'vip-details'})


for li in product.findAll('div', {'class': 'attribute'}):
    print(li)
```

The result is something like this:

```
[...]
<div class="attribute"><span class="name">Rok</span><span class="value">2019</span></div>
<div class="attribute"><span class="name">Kilometry</span><span class="value">12</span></div>
[...]
```

How to get access to 2 span element? in my case to value `2019` and `12`

I tried to use such solutions but without success:

```
for li in product.findAll('div', {'class': 'attribute'}):
    print(li.span.span)
```

and

```
for li in product.findAll('div', {'class': 'attribute'}):
    print(li.span[1])
```

How can I access the second `span` of an element in my loop?

Comment: maybe you can try `for li in product.findAll('div', {'class': 'attribute'}): print(li.findAll('span')[1].text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_next`()

```
for li in product.findAll('div', {'class': 'attribute'}):
    print(li.find_next("span" , class_='value').text)
```

Or Use css selector.

```
for li in product.select('.attribute .value'):
   print(li.text)
```

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#url website
url = 'https://www.gumtree.pl/a-samochody-osobowe/krakow/honda-civic-1-5-sport-mt-2019/1006295441720911232816609'
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
product = page_soup.select_one('.vip-details')

for li in product.select('.attribute .value'):
   print(li.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my expected result by using two loops:

```
for li in product.findAll('div', {'class': 'attribute'}):
    for value in li.findAll('span', {'class': 'value'}):
        print(value.text)
```

if there is a simpler solution to the problem, I invite you to comment.